# Python 3.8 assignment expression in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-assignment-expression

I'm trying to use the new [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#site-py) for the first time and could use some help.

Given three lines of log outputs:

```
sin = """Writing 93 records to /data/newstates-900.03-07_07/top100.newstates-900.03-07_07/Russia.seirdc.March6-900.12.csv ..
Writing 100 records to /data/newstates-900.03-07_07/top100.newstates-900.03-07_07/India.seirdc.March6-900.6.csv ..
Writing 100 records to /data/newstates-900.03-07_07/top100.newstates-900.03-07_07/US.seirdc.March6-900.15.csv ..
"""
```

The intent is to extract just the `State` (*Russia*, *India* and *US*) and the record count (93,100,100) .  So the desired result is:

```
[['Russia',93],['India',100],['US',100]]
```

This requires the following steps to be translated into Python:

- Convert each line into a list element
- Split by space e.g.  `['Writing', '93', 'records', 'to', '/data/newstates-900.03-07_07/top100.newstates-900.03-07_07/Russia.seirdc.March6-900.12.csv', '..']`
- Split the fifth such token by '/' and retain the last element:  e.g. `Russia.seirdc.March6-900.12.csv`
- Split that element by '.' and retain the first (0'th) element  e.g. `Russia`

Here is my incorrect attempt:

```
import fileinput
y = [[ z[4].split('/')[-1].split('.')[0],z[1]] 
     for (z:=x.split(' ')) in 
     (x:=sin if sin else fileinput.input()).splitlines())]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this good enough?

```py
[[(wrds := line.split())[4].split("/")[-1].split('.')[0], wrds[1]] for line in sin.splitlines()]
```

I find using assignment expression redundant. You can also do this:

```py
[[line.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0], line.split()[1]] for line in sin.splitlines()]
```

Comment: The assignment is not redundant: your second one does the `split()` twice. Imagine if that were an expensive operation. I'm awarding because this is a good answer.  Actually the second one is kind of clever but also cheating: it makes use of the '/' is only existing in the last space-delimited token.

Comment: @javadba I agree with you but what I meant was in this specific problem. Also if my answer is what you were looking for you can check the checkmark near my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have a chance: I would actually like to see the doubly nested structure. Consider not using a trick to collapse this into a single level: i.e. the OP is a toy example but the intent is to understand how to do multiple levels of nesting (where the multi levels are truly needed) and with the assignment expression.

Comment: re: doubly nested structure. You can wait on this : i'm going to create a separate question in which it will _not_ be possible to squash the levels. It will involve grouping and aggregation operations on numerical data.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth you can also get this using regex as well which would probably be more preferred/efficient.

```
[list(reversed(l)) for l in re.findall(r'Writing (\d+).+\/([A-Z,a-z]+)\.', sin)]
```

Or more accurately *(to convert the int)* and for readability *(as per [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in comments)*:

```
[[country, int(count)] for count, country in re.findall(r'Writing (\d+).+\/([A-Z,a-z]+)\.', sin)]
```

Comment: `[ [country, int(count)] for count, country in ... ]` would be more readable (and match the requested output better).

Comment: Useful approach.  I do want to use the `walrus` for many other data munging tasks that do not lend to clever heuristics: but  specifically for test parsing your way makes much sense.  The addition by @chepner is also helpful.

Comment: Oh you just removed the `reverse(list)`.  I think that is also helpful to mention (and not just lose completely)

Comment: I removed the reverse as it's more readable and it makes converting the count to int easier as well

Comment: Ya i "got" that - but the trick of doing reverse() is actually an additional one to keep in toolkit . Well I absorbed it already - but future readers will see the end product and not that (interesting) intermediate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
results = []
for line in sin.split('..'):
    if len(z := line.split(' ')) > 1 :
        results.append([line.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0], z[1]])
```

Comment: pls see above: the accepted answer uses it in a `for` comprehension. You can also refer to the linked PEP docs.